# How to export a multi line CSV that every item is in one cell?

Tags: powershell, csv, user-interface, active-directory

I'm kinda new into the PowerShell world related to building gui's but I've managed to create a gui that in a few words, searches users in an AD and if the looked up information is correct it will store it on a CSV with the Out-File command.

An example looks like this.

```
 Enabled         : False
 Locked          : False
 DisplayName     : John Doe_test
 GivenName       : John
 SurName         : doe_test
 SamAccountName  : johndoe
 Mail            : ftestaddress@somemail.com
 OfficePhone     : 9999
 Last Logon      : 31/12/1600 21:00:00
 Date Created    : 7/6/2020 18:02:56
 passwordlastset : 7/6/2020 18:02:56
```

And the code that outputs that is this one (this is the part that searches the user, displays it on a read only textbox and if the end user is right with the click of another button it will store the data. (The Write Host value is only to test the data, otherwise I'll have to enter to the csv file every time I store it.

```bsh
$Formselected.controls.addrange(@($datousr,$save_btn))
$datousr.Text= Get-ADUser -filter {DisplayName -eq $username} -Properties * |Select-Object Enabled, @{Expression={$_.LockedOut};Label='Locked';}, DisplayName, GivenName, SurName, SamAccountName, Mail, OfficePhone, @{ Expression ={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}; Label='Last Logon';}, @{Expression={$_.Created};Label='Date Created';}, passwordlastset | Out-String
$data_usr=$datousr.text
$save_btn.Add_Click{
    Write-Host "$data_usr"
    $data_usr |Out-File "C:\scripts\data load.csv"  -Encoding UTF8 -Append -Force
}
```

I want to know, because it's driving me nuts how to assing "enable" on A1 and the result, which is "False" on A2 and so on because every item is in a line.
I've tried exporting to csv, but, because it comes from a variable it only stores the length of the output, not the value.

I'd like to be stored in this way:

```
Enabled  Locked Username
False   False   JohnDoe
```

Comment: that is not a CSV file. [*grin*] it is a somewhat structured plain text file. have you tried looking at the `Export-CSV` cmdlet? it is _designed_ for exporting an object to a CSV file ...

Comment: Yes! When I export to CSV it retuns me this `#TYPE System.String
Length
368
`

Comment: the `#TYPE` is because you forgot to use the `-NoTypeInformation` parameter. [*grin*] the `Length` column with a value of `368` means that your object is not a structured object. the reason is this >>> `| Out-String` <<< that _destroys your structured objects_ and gives you a string. the `Export-CSV` cmdlet REQUIRES a structured object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Export-CSV` has a switch called `-NoTypeInformation`. With that appended to the cmdlet it saves the data only. However, you need to keep the data as **Object** for this, not converted to string as you have it now.
To do this, change the code block where the user information is gathered from AD into this:

```
# properties DistinguishedName, Enabled, GivenName, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID, Surname, UserPrincipalName are returned by default.
$props    = 'LockedOut','DisplayName','EmailAddress','OfficePhone','LastLogonDate','Created','PasswordLastSet'

# use the `script:` scope on the variable, so the button click has access to it
$script:data_usr = Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$username'" -Properties $props -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
                   Select-Object Enabled, 
                                 @{Name = 'Locked'; Expression = {$_.LockedOut}},
                                 DisplayName, GivenName, SurName, SamAccountName,
                                 @{Name = 'Mail'; Expression = {$_.EmailAddress}},
                                 OfficePhone, 
                                 @{Name = 'Last Logon'; Expression = {$_.LastLogonDate}},
                                 @{Name = 'Date Created'; Expression = {$_.Created}},
                                 PasswordLastSet

# display the data in the text box by formatting it as list and converting it to a string
$datousr.Text = ($data_usr | Format-List | Out-String)
```

Then in the code where you save the data to CSV, do:

```
$save_btn.Add_Click({
    Write-Host $data_usr  # display in the console
    # save as proper CSV file (append to if the file already exists)
    $script:data_usr | Export-Csv -Path "C:\scripts\data_load.csv" -Encoding UTF8 -Append -NoTypeInformation
})
```

Please note that it is better to name the properties you need from Get-ADUser then to use  `-Properties *`. You don't need to add the properties returned by default (see the first code comment)

Also, I would recommend searching for the user on a user attribute other then the users DisplayName, because this tends the users of your GUI to enter variations like `Bloggs, Joe` vs. `Joe Bloggs`. EmailAddress could be more precise.

Comment: Ohhhh thanks a lot!
I wasn't that far off. In previous version on the code I did something similar, but I didn't declared the $props! Thank you a veeeeeeeery lot!

Comment: Thanks Theo, It was a great help, and a very good guidance on how I will have to code in the future. (I am a self taught on free times and sometimes I miss something so obvious that I can only laugh myself off)